# ConcurrentModificationException while using Iterator<Node>

Tags: java, javafx, iterator, gridpane, observablelist

I was trying to delete a **row** of JavaFX GridPane with JavaFX Rectangles and I found no way to do so but **copying the squares above to one row below**. Here is my code to do that but it keeps throwing **ConcurrentModificationAcception**.

```
static void copyAbove(int rowToBeDisappear, GridPane mainGrid) {
        for (int y = (rowToBeDisappear-1); 0 <= y ; y--) {
            for (int x = 0; x <= 9; x++) {
                Iterator<Node> iterator = mainGrid.getChildren().iterator();
                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Node sqr = iterator.next();
                    if (sqr == getSqrByIndex(x,y,mainGrid)) {
                        iterator.remove();
                        mainGrid.add(sqr,x,(y+1));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The error

> Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
> at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator$VetoableIteratorDecorator.checkForComodification(VetoableListDecorator.java:714)
> at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator$VetoableIteratorDecorator.hasNext(VetoableListDecorator.java:682)
> at Main.copyAbove(Main.java:%local_code_row_nvm_this%)

Comment: `iterator` of nonconcurrent collection has `fail-fast` mechanism (like `for-each`).

Comment: Use the `ListIterator` which allows you to add during iteration (via the Iterator)

Comment: this smells strongly like an x-y-problem (_trying to delete a row of GridPane_), from your sparce description it looks like just removing all nodes in a given row should do what you need. Please provide a [mcve] of what you __really__ are trying to achieve and what exactly isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Slaw for pointing out the flaw in my solution.

You can't iterate an iterator and modify its backing collection (except through that iterator's `remove` method) at the same time. Store any structural changes you'd like done on the collection to a temporary collection, then perform them after iterating.

If `getSqrByIndex()` is guaranteed to return at most one `Node` given an `x` and a `y`, then the following code will not cause CMEs:

```
Node node = null;

Iterator<Node> iterator = mainGrid.getChildren().iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Node sqr = iterator.next();
    if (sqr == getSqrByIndex(x,y,mainGrid)) {
        node = sqr;
    }
}

if (node != null) {
    mainGrid.getChildren().remove(node);
    mainGrid.add(node, x, y + 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked...

Answer (score 0):

I’m a total idiot and new to this so this may be wrong, but why not use a for() loop instead of while()? I believe it keeps it in scope so that you can call iterater.remove(). **Also, it may be throwing that because you’re adding objects into your iterator at the same time that you’re iterating. I would try separating the points in which you add and remove objects.**

Comment: The type of loop does not matter in this case. The problem is modifying the iterator's source in ways other than `Iterator#remove()`.